# How to add a button in a tooltip in extjs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a simple extjs form, where all the fields look like plain text when rendered. 
When user hovers over the field, i need to show a edit icon (which i am thinking would be a tooltip) next to the field (indicating that the field is editable). And when user clicks on it, the field will get focus and made editable.

Is tooltip the right component ? If not, how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A tooltip would be a bad approach - mostly because if the person mouses away from the field, the tooltip would vanish.

A simpler approach would be to include the edit icon at all times, inside the same container as the field. The edit icon should be invisible normally. Then, when the person moves the mouse into the container, make the icon visible. On mouse-exit from the container, make the icon invisible again.